# Unpack JSON lines to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, unpack

I am dealing with the JSON line format and trying to "unpack" the dictionary objects inside a single list. Since it's using a list to save the dictionary object, I haven't found any post that deals with the issue before. The data looks like this, which there are bunch of nested dictionaries inside a list object:

```
0        [{'created_at': 'Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 202...
1        [{'created_at': 'Sat Jul 25 22:30:14 +0000 202...
2        [{'created_at': 'Sat May 30 02:22:04 +0000 202...
3        [{'created_at': 'Tue May 05 16:54:05 +0000 202...
4        [{'created_at': 'Sat Jun 20 13:50:23 +0000 202...
                               ...                        
17453    [{'created_at': 'Mon Apr 13 01:01:10 +0000 202...
17454    [{'created_at': 'Fri Jul 17 09:00:50 +0000 202...
17455    [{'created_at': 'Sun Jun 21 00:51:54 +0000 202...
17456    [{'created_at': 'Tue Jun 02 18:23:49 +0000 202...
17457    [{'created_at': 'Thu May 28 00:27:01 +0000 202...
```

What I've tried now is:

```
with open('data') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
df_inter = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df_inter.columns = ['json_element']
```

For the nested ditionaries, I would use `pd.json_normalize(df_inter['json_element'].apply(json.loads))` provided by this [post](https://ram-parameswaran22.medium.com/a-relatively-faster-approach-for-reading-json-lines-file-into-pandas-dataframe-90b57353fd38). However, how could I unpack the multiple dictionary-objects into a single row?

**EDIT**

Since the data is huge, I'll provide a partial single line of data:

```
[{'created_at': 'Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020', 'id': 1272262651100434433, 'id_str': '1272262651100434433', 'truncated': False, 'display_text_range': [0, 243], 'entities': {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Tenet', 'indices': [82, 88]}], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [], 'urls': [], 'media': [{'id': 1272262640753094656, 'id_str': '1272262640753094656', 'indices': [244, 267], 'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eaf8IYsWsAAHVHV.jpg'...}]
```

Comment: It depends of the structure of your dictionaries, whether each element of the list has same structure and how many nested dictionaries are there. Provide more comprehensive sample data

Comment: Thanks, I've put an example data in the post.

Comment: @Kapocsi You're right. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `data` file looks like this:

```
[{"created_at": "Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020", "id": 1272262651100434433, "id_str": "1272262651100434433", "truncated": false, "display_text_range": [0, 243], "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "Tenet", "indices": [82, 88]}], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": [], "media": [{"id": 1272262640753094656, "id_str": "1272262640753094656", "indices": [244, 267], "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eaf8IYsWsAAHVHV.jpg"}]}}]
[{"created_at": "Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020", "id": 1272262651100434433, "id_str": "1272262651100434433", "truncated": false, "display_text_range": [0, 243], "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "Tenet", "indices": [82, 88]}], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": [], "media": [{"id": 1272262640753094656, "id_str": "1272262640753094656", "indices": [244, 267], "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eaf8IYsWsAAHVHV.jpg"}]}}]
[{"created_at": "Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020", "id": 1272262651100434433, "id_str": "1272262651100434433", "truncated": false, "display_text_range": [0, 243], "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "Tenet", "indices": [82, 88]}], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": [], "media": [{"id": 1272262640753094656, "id_str": "1272262640753094656", "indices": [244, 267], "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eaf8IYsWsAAHVHV.jpg"}]}}]
[{"created_at": "Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020", "id": 1272262651100434433, "id_str": "1272262651100434433", "truncated": false, "display_text_range": [0, 243], "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "Tenet", "indices": [82, 88]}], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": [], "media": [{"id": 1272262640753094656, "id_str": "1272262640753094656", "indices": [244, 267], "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eaf8IYsWsAAHVHV.jpg"}]}}]
[{"created_at": "Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020", "id": 1272262651100434433, "id_str": "1272262651100434433", "truncated": false, "display_text_range": [0, 243], "entities": {"hashtags": [{"text": "Tenet", "indices": [82, 88]}], "symbols": [], "user_mentions": [], "urls": [], "media": [{"id": 1272262640753094656, "id_str": "1272262640753094656", "indices": [244, 267], "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/Eaf8IYsWsAAHVHV.jpg"}]}}]
```

you can use the following code to get one dataframe row per line in the jsonl file.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data') as f:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(line)[0] for line in f)
```

Your df will look like this:

```
                       created_at                   id               id_str  truncated display_text_range                                           entities
0  Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020  1272262651100434433  1272262651100434433      False           [0, 243]  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Tenet', 'indices': [82...
1  Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020  1272262651100434433  1272262651100434433      False           [0, 243]  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Tenet', 'indices': [82...
2  Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020  1272262651100434433  1272262651100434433      False           [0, 243]  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Tenet', 'indices': [82...
3  Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020  1272262651100434433  1272262651100434433      False           [0, 243]  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Tenet', 'indices': [82...
4  Sun Jun 14 20:20:28 +0000 2020  1272262651100434433  1272262651100434433      False           [0, 243]  {'hashtags': [{'text': 'Tenet', 'indices': [82...
```

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------              --------------  -----
 0   created_at          5 non-null      object
 1   id                  5 non-null      int64
 2   id_str              5 non-null      object
 3   truncated           5 non-null      bool
 4   display_text_range  5 non-null      object
 5   entities            5 non-null      object
dtypes: bool(1), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 333.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. It's amazing and simple code without unpacking the list and transforming it into a dataframe.